# El significado de "delineado" en "delineado de barbas"

Tags: gramática, significado-en-contexto

Quisiera confirmar si "delineado" se usa como sustantivo y si su significado es "to outline" o "to draw up" en el siguiente aporte, que pertenece a un grupo social privado en línea:

"Buen día. Me pongo a sus órdenes con cortes de cabello para caballeros y niños, depilación de cejas y delineado de barbas."

Comment: Sí, "delineado" es un sustantivo y el término correcto en ese caso.

Comment: OK, now we're cooking. Yes, outlining: https://opentextbc.ca/barberingtechniquesforhairstylists/chapter/outlining-techniques/ But I repeat, we only translate from English to Spanish. I already said this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El término que se utiliza en barberías es **perfilado**.

> Perfilado de barba

[image]

<sub>[*Fuente de la imagen*](https://www.barbazul.com/blogs/blog/como-perfilar-la-barba)</sub>

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!